# I need to translate 3d points relative to a triangle as if the triangle was somewhere else

Tags: c, 3d, rotational-matrices

I posted this on twitter a while ago but seeing how none of my followers appears to be a math/programming genius, I'll try my luck here as well. I got here because I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706331/how-to-rotate-a-3d-tringle-flat-against-the-wall) which might contain part of my solution.

I described my problem in the following [pdf](http://users.telenet.be/skorinai/mathproblem.pdf) document, containing a picture of what I'm trying to achieve.

To give some more details, I divided the pentagon's of a dodecahedron (12 pentagons) into triangles (5/pentagon, 60 triangles in total), then collected a set of data points relative to each of these triangles.

The idea is to generate terrain meshes for each individual triangle.
To do so, the data must be represented flat, in a 32K x 32K square (idTech4 Megatexture)

I have vaguely heard of transformation matrices, which when set up properly, could do the trick of passing all the data points trough them to have them show up in the right place.

I looked at this source code [here](http://www.fastgraph.com/makegames/3drotation/3dsrce.html) but I don't understand how I'm supposed to get the points in and/or out of there, not to mention how to do the setup so I can present each point in turn and get the result point back.

I got as fas as identifying the point that belongs in the back right corner. All my 3D points are originally stored in latitude / longitude pairs. I retrieve the 3D vectors this way:

```
coord getcoord(point* p) 
{
    coord c;
    c.x=cos(p->lat*pi/180.l) * cos(p->lon*pi/180.l);
    c.y=cos(p->lat*pi/180.l) * sin(p->lon*pi/180.l);
    c.z=sin(p->lat*pi/180.l);
    return c;
};
```

My thought is that if I can find the center of my triangle, and discover how to offset my angles so the vector from the center of my sphere to the middle of the triangle moves to 90N then my points would already be in the right plane if I rotated them all along the same angles. If I then convert them all to 3d and subtracti the radius from y, they'll be at the correct y position as well.

Then all I'd need to do is the rotation, the scaling, and the moving to the final position.

There are several kinds of 'centers' for a triangle, I think the one I need is the one that is equidistant to the corners of the triangle (Circumcenter?)

But then there might be an easier approach to the whole problem so while I continue my own research, perhaps some of you can help pointing me in the right direction.

It appears as if some sample data is in order, here are a few of these triangles in obj file format:

```
v 0.000000 0.000000 3396.000000
v 2061.582356 0.000000 2698.646733
v 637.063983 1960.681333 2698.646733
f 1 2 3
```

And another:

```
v -938.631230 2888.810129 1518.737455
v 637.063983 1960.681333 2698.646733
v 1030.791271 3172.449325 637.064076
f 1 2 3
```

You will notice that each point is at a distance of 3396 from 0,0,0
I mentioned 'on the sphere' meaning that the face away from the center of the sphere is the face that needs to become the 'top' when translated into the square.

Theoretically all these triangles should in fact have identical sizes, but due to rounding errors in the math that generated them, this might not be entirely true.

If I'm not mistaken I already took measures to ensure that the first point you see here is always the one opposite the longest border, so it's the one that should go in the far left corner (testing the above 2 samples confirms this, but I'm measuring anyway just to be sure)
Both legs leading away from this point should theoretically have the same length as well, but again rounding errors might slightly offset that.

If I've done it correctly then the longer side is 1,113587 times longer than the 2 shorter sides. Assuming those are identical, then doing some goal seeking in excel, I can deduct that the final points, assuming I was just translating this triangle, should look like:

```
v 16384.000000 0.000000 16384.000000
v -16384.000000 0.000000 9916.165306
v 9916.165306 0.000000 -16384.000000
f 1 2 3
```

So I need to setup the matrix to do this transformation, preferably using the 4x4 matrix as explained below.

Comment: I fail to see your problem. Is your triangle truly `on the sphere`? Do you have trouble projecting the sphere onto a plane? Or do you mean by `on the sphere` that the triangle is part of a discretization of the surface of the sphere?

Comment: Each of the 3 points of the triangle is at a distance equal to the radius of the sphere. In fact in their original form they are just latitude/longitude angles. If it's easier to do transformations before I've converted them to x,y,z coordinates then that can be done too. The sphere's center is at 0,0,0
The data points which I need to convert, ofcourse, are not on the sphere, but are relative to this triangle. So when I know how to translate the triangle so it shows up where it should, then the data points can follow suit.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using transform matrices. The 3d transform matrix is a 4x4 data structure which describes a translation and rotation (and possibly a scale). Once you have a matrix you can transform a point like so

```
 result.x = (tmp->pt.x * m->element[0][0]) + 
            (tmp->pt.y * m->element[1][0]) + 
            (tmp->pt.z * m->element[2][0]) + 
            m->element[3][0];

 result.y = (tmp->pt.x * m->element[0][1]) + 
            (tmp->pt.y * m->element[1][1]) + 
            (tmp->pt.z * m->element[2][1]) + 
            m->element[3][1];
 result.z = (tmp->pt.x * m->element[0][2]) + 
            (tmp->pt.y * m->element[1][2]) + 
            (tmp->pt.z * m->element[2][2]) + 
            m->element[3][2];
 int w = (tmp->pt.x * m->element[0][3]) + (tmp->pt.y * m->element[1][3])
      + (tmp->pt.z * m->element[2][3]) + m->element[3][3];
 if (w!=0 || w!=1)
 result.x/=w; result.y/=w; result.z/=w;
```

This will transform the 3D point pt by the matrix m. If you now a little matrix math you'll see i'm just multiplying my origin point as a vector against the matrix (and doing a little normalization if it is a skew matrix.) Matrices can be multiplied together to form complicated transformations so they are very useful.

For details on making matrices suggest reading this link.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix

Comment: The source code I posted in my question appeared to hint at using 3x4 matrices. You are suggesting a 4x4 matrix. The source code I have leaves some hints on how to go about setting up specific transformations, based on 3x4 matrices. Which leaves me a bit lost now that we're talking about different matrices. I found that setting up your matrix in this matter leaves all my points at their original position, which is a good starting point I guess:
    `matrix id4matrix={
    {1,0,0,0},
    {0,1,0,0},
    {0,0,1,0},
    {0,0,0,1},
    };`

Comment: I'm using the much more common projection matrix which defines all translations and rotations (including scaling which is why you need the 4th row.) To apply a translation just change the final column. [3][0] = delta x; [3][1] delta y ; [3][2] = deltaz. Rotations are a bit more tricky but I can help you if you really need it. Its really just about inserting the right trig functions into the right cells.

Comment: The code may use 3x4 matrices because the last row of a 4x4 transform matrix is always 0 0 0 1, for any combination of rotations, translations and scaling.  So the last row can be omitted (presumably to save space) if the code that applies the transforms acts as if it was there.

Comment: Forgot to add: in the 4x4 system, a point is {x, y, z, 1}, so you may see the last component omitted.  However, I've seen the last component set to 0 to define points "at infinity" (in a defined direction, but infinitely far away); the 4x4 transforms work as expected on those points too (that is, translations and scaling have no effect, but rotations do -- very elegant).

Comment: Good to know! I'm going to have to check now why we were messing with the bottom row in our code ... although it's probably a hack for something else.

Comment: I've seen the sine cosine things in that example code so I could take that from there, the real trick is going to be figuring out what angles everything needs to be translated with.
Thank you @RussS for mentioning the scaling. You pointed me to a serious flaw in my logic. I am projecting my points as if they come from the center of my sphere, so the larger my triangle, the further apart the points above my triangle should become. I think I can solve that problem first by just multiplying the radius of my sphere with something so I know the result will fit in a 32K x 32K box.